# How to print groups of all local users?

Tags: c, unix

I want to print all groups of users stored in /etc/passwd. Seems easy enough, I can just use getpwent() and getgrouplist(). I came with this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <pwd.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <grp.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv){

    struct passwd* user;
    int nGroups = 20;
    gid_t* groups;
    groups = malloc(nGroups * sizeof(gid_t));
    struct group* gr;
    while(user = getpwent()){
        printf("%s : ", user->pw_name);
        getgrouplist(user->pw_name, user->pw_gid, groups, &nGroups);
        int i;
        for(i = 0; i < nGroups; ++i){
            gr = getgrgid(groups[i]);
            if(gr){
                printf("%s ", gr->gr_name);
            }  
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    free(groups);
    return 0;
}
```

It gives me this output:

```
root : root 
daemon : daemon 
bin : bin 
.
.
.
pulse : pulse root 
ricenwind : ricenwind adm root root root root root root 
vboxadd : daemon
```

which is clearly wrong, as for example using

```
groups ricenwind
```

gives me:

```
ricenwind : ricenwind adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare
```

Comment: After you done fixing your code, run a Memory check tool on it. Valgrind says that a `free` is missing `total heap usage: 215 allocs, 214 frees, 59,802 bytes allocated`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read [the `getgrouplist` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getgrouplist.3.html) you will see

> Up to `*ngroups` of these groups are returned in the array `groups`.

The `ngroups` argument is not only set by the function, it's also used by the function to know how many structures you have allocated for the `groups` argument.

You need to "reset" the `nGroups` variable before calling `getgrouplist`, otherwise the old value set by the previous call to the function will be used:

```
nGroups = 20;
getgrouplist(user->pw_name, user->pw_gid, groups, &nGroups);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using a simple bash script as

## !/bin/bash

grep "/bin/bash" /etc/passwd

it would do the result,bcoz all the local user will have /bin/bash or /bin/sh as their shell